# What percentage of a DRAM cell size is occupied by the transistor and/or the capacitor?

Tags: solid-state-devices, dram

Assuming that we have a 1T1C DRAM cell manufactured at 22nm process. Based on [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7047083) we can have an idea about the cell area (0.026 um^2 in this case). However, I could not find specific information about the percentage of the area consumed by the transistor and the capacitor, respectively. What makes it a bit more difficult is the fact that different type of capacitors could be used in different cells (trench or stacked). Since I'm not a device engineer myself, does anyone know some ballpark numbers on this (or maybe where can I look for - to deduct these number from)?

**EDIT:**
I found the "CMOS VLSI Design" book by Weste and Harris in my library, back from my student years. The following image leads me to believe that since the trench capacitor is extended on the 3rd dimension "under" the drain n-well, it has no real impact on the area - or am I wrong?

[image: DRAM cells design]

Comment: I can’t immediately answer your question but I can tell you that 22nm tech means that the smallest feature size is 22nm, so I would expect a RAM cell to be several times that size.

Comment: https://blocksandfiles.com/2020/04/13/dram-is-stuck-in-a-10nm-process-trap/#:~:text=DRAM%20cell%20sizes%20are%20measured,16)%20%3D%202%2C048%20square%20nanometres.
This source estimates the area to be 6 to 8 times the area of the feature size squared.

Comment: @Frog Sure,but 0.026 square micrometres is an area corresponding to a 161 nm by 161 nm square, for example. So that matches what you wrote fairly well.

Comment: My reading is 22nm x 22nm x 8, so 4000 square nano-nanometres. 4x10^-15 in scientific notation.

Comment: Meanwhile this source https://www.techinsights.com/blog/memory/micron-1a-dram-technology says 0.3Gb per square mm, but that’s based on 14nm tech, so 22nm will be about double that area.

Comment: @Frog Please see my edited question, it might add something useful

Comment: .. working through, we have 2.5x10^14 cells per square metre, or 2.5x 10^8 per square mm, which is 0.25Gb.  That doesn’t seem to add up since that’s almost the 0.3Gb claimed for 14nm tech

Comment: Fig 1 and 2 in the linked paper show the gate and capacitor from all 3 axes.  The capacitor is enormous in volume, but very tall, so the 2D area is roughly the same as the metal contacts.  Maybe 25% of the cell area is the capacitor.  Note that the paper you linked is for eDRAM made on a logic process, which is made differently than conventional DRAM (mentioned in your title).

Comment: @user1850479 Indeed. Which also seems to (kind of) agree with the diagram I found in the book. I couldn't find info for a 22nm DRAM cell. What I found though is this: https://semiengineering.com/micron-d1%CE%B1-the-most-advanced-node-yet-on-dram/

They state a cell area of 1672nm2 for a 14nm process - by using a scaling factor of ~2.46 I calculated an area of ~4126nm2, which is FAR smaller than what the previous paper states. I'm genuinely confused.

Comment: 22nm is a logic node and would not normally have DRAM cells (only in special cases as with the eDRAM paper you linked). Which are you asking about?

Comment: I just found out that the process to create eDRAM is completely different than "normal" DRAM. So let me rephrase: in "regular" DRAM, what percentage of the cell area is being occupied by the capacitor? Regardless of the process used.

Comment: In regular dram essentially the entire cell area is capacitor. They're packed almost edge to edge with nothing in between.

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you! Could you please write an answer and elaborate a bit more (if you're bored, just point me to some literature)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to your revised question in the comments, essentially the entire cell area is covered in capacitors:

[image]

(Taken from this article:  https://www.stinstruments.com/microelectronics/ultra-high-resolution-sem-observation-of-dram-capacitors/ )

In cross section you can see why:

[image]

(Taken from this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bln-v9LmZ3E )

The capacitors are built on top of the metalization, which is on top of the transistors.  As a result of this 3D stacking, the capacitor layer does not have to share space with anything else (aside maybe from a bit of dead area due to the hexagonal packing).

This is in contrast to the (much less common) eDRAM cells linked above, which are made on a (modified) logic process rather than a DRAM process.  Since they have to fit into chips logic (e.g. for CPU cache), they're more awkwardly tucked into either the metal wires or etched into the silicon below the transistors and can't be packed as tightly (although as cache they're also usually designed to be fast rather than as dense as possible).